# ASRock asrock H110M-ITX/ac Audio Issue

Tags: 14.04, drivers, sound, headphones

I'm Patrick

I'm fairly new to computers as I'm only 16 and just built my first computer. It is a mini ITX build using an asrock h110m-itx/ac motherboard and I use it primarily for coding, schoolwork, and gaming. Unfortunately I am having trouble with audio using this motherboard and honestly have no idea why. My case is a Coolermaster Elite 110 Mini ITX case, it comes with a separate front panel with a headphone and mic jack, when I plug in headphones there is no audio.  I have checked in the settings and there is an Analog output listed and the volume on it is all the way up. I have Wine and have attempted to install the audio drivers included on a CD that came with my motherboard, but to no avail. I also made sure that all the cords coming from the front panel are plugged into the correct ports on the motherboard. Any ideas on how to get my sound working?

Comment: FYI... You can't install drivers in WINE. That's not how it works.

Answer (score 0):

First off, did you try attaching speakers / headphones to the rear analog output in case you have a defective cable / connector?

Otherwise, I notice that your motherboard has a RealTek 892 audio codec, which another user had issues with. You can see their post here and try out their solution: [ALC892 Low sound issue fixed with changing alsa config, why does it work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456425/alc892-low-sound-issue-fixed-with-changing-alsa-config-why-does-it-work)