# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS got stuck in a login loop

Tags: 14.04, boot, 16.04, login, alsa

I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04LTS Desktop. After entering my login details, the screen gets black and I am again shown the login screen. I'm perfectly sure that there's no invalidation in my login details. I've tried many possible solutions that I could from an another similar post:
[Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop), and many others, but it just doesn't seem to work. i"ve stuck over this for a week now.

Also, when the black screen shows up, I get the following message:

```
libkmod:ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:635 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa.conf line 45: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
```

Few days back, I did some changes in the "alsa.conf" file, to fix low sound issues in the system. I followed the post [ALC892 Low sound issue fixed with changing alsa config, why does it work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456425/alc892-low-sound-issue-fixed-with-changing-alsa-config-why-does-it-work) At the end of the file, I added the line:

```
snd-hda-intel model=generic
```

But later, I commented it out.

Comment: @HenryWHHackv2.0 Read the question properly. I've already mentioned that post.

Comment: Since you suspect the alsa configuration file, please [edit] your question to include the relevant portion e.g. `cat -net /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf | tail`. While it's creditable that you've tried to solve your issue using "as many as possible" of the answers from the linked question, it would help us is you could at least briefly summarize which ones specifically you tried and what the results were.

Comment: What's in `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa.conf` – specifically line 45?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/299407/ububtu-16-04lts-got-stuck-in-a-login-loop

Comment: sorry as @DavidFoerster says that should have been `cat -net /etc/modprobe.d/alsa.conf | tail` (the reason for using `cat -net` is that it can highlight certain non-printing characters that may have crept in)

Comment: This happened to me after a recent upgrade of 16.04LTS. I could login to the guest account. I created a new account with superuser privileges and this worked fine. I tried the solutions given in the answer you quoted and they didn't help. Deleting my old user account and recreating it seemed to solve the problem. However the problem came back and this time effected all user accounts. I have reverted to 14.04LTS which seems not to have the problem (at least for now).